# How to position a div in a li to the parent ul

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf7w646y/)):

```css
ul { 
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}
li { 
    border:1px solid grey; 
    display:inline-block; 
}
div { 
    position:absolute; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        One
    </li>
    <li>
        Two
        <div>Some content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This positions the div directly below `Two`.

Is it possible to move the div to the far left (i.e. below `One`) **with just CSS**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the parent UL to `position: relative` will allow for absolute positioning from within a child LI.

```css
ul { 
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    position: relative;
}
li { 
    border:1px solid grey; 
    display:inline-block; 
}
div { 
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        One
    </li>
    <li>
        Two
        <div>Some content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```